# I can't install any packages without it failing - I get an error about config.dat being locked - how can I fix this?

Tags: 12.10, apt, dpkg, manpage

I had a power failure on my laptop, so I ended up crashing in the middle of a package installation. How do I fix this error?

```
jrg@atlantis:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up man-db (2.6.3-1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jrg@atlantis:~$
```